# TableAdapter wizard not generating INSERT method - UPDATE and DELETE fine

Tags: .net, vb.net, tableadapter

I have inherited a project with an Access backend, using TableAdapters which I've not used before.

Most of the tables in the schema work fine, but a single one is not generating the INSERT statement and insert method.

I have checked everything mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812(vs.80).aspx

The adapter is using a simple query on a single table, the checkboxes for generating statements and methods are ticked and the table has a primary key. UPDATE and DELETE work fine.

Is there anything else that could be affecting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the xsd file and look at the properties of the TableAdaptor, you should have an entry for `InsertCommand`. If this is missing you can add it manually.

This assumes you are using an xsd file obviously.

**Edit:**

Have you tried adding a new TableAdaptor using the wizard attached to the same table to see if it generates without the insert command?

Comment: Yeah, I can add it manually, but that means that out of all the tables in the project, this single one has a manual insert command to worry about - it's a bit of a pain maintenance wise, and I'd rather find out why the wizard isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried adding a new TableAdaptor using the wizard attached to the same table to see if it generates without the insert command?

Comment: Ahhh! Didn't think of that, that seems to have done the trick - add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct as it a) worked and b) solved my problem, but what I actually did, to avoid potentially breaking relationships, was to go into the wizard, delete the query text, rebuild using the table selector thingy, and finish the wizard again - that seemed to work in the same way as generating a whole new one TableAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I noticed something the table had no primary key, solve it by adding the primary key, now it works fine, have you tried that?

Comment: interesting idea -- i'll have to try it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and discovered that the `INSERT` command was not created if I had omitted fields from the dataset that were `NOT NULL` in the database.  Once I included the `NOT NULL` fields in the dataset, the `INSERT` command was created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I went to my first tableadapter query and changed it from "Select fid1, fid2, fid3 from filename"  to  "Select * from tablename" and checked that I wanted the inserts, updates, etc generated.  It generated all new commands.  Worked great.